# getParseObject() returns null

Tags: java, android, pointers, parse-platform

I don't know what's wrong with my code, that it always returns `null` when I use `getParseObject()`.

I'm using parse.com to save my data, and in one table I used one file as a pointer. I have a `Game` class that has `ImgName` as a `Pointer<Gallery>` to a `gallery` class.

Now I want to retrieve the `ImgName` value, so this is what I did:

```
public Adapter(Context context) {
    super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
        public ParseQuery create() {
            ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Game");
            query.include("ImgName");
            return query;
        }
    });
}

// Customize the layout by overriding getItemView
@Override
public View getItemView(final ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (v == null) {
        v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.list_item_landing_cards, null);
    }
    ParseObject gallery =  object.getParseObject("ImgName");
    String name=gallery.getString("name");
    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
    nameTextView.setText(name);
```

But I'm getting `null` all the time. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Object is a newly created parseobject, how to you expect getparseobject to return anything other than null?

Comment: I updated the code , still giving me null ... please tell me what's wrong

Comment: The updated code looks more correct. Are you sure that all of your game objects has a pointer in the "ImgName" column?

Comment: Could you verify that the column name is correct and that it has a value...

Comment: The name is correct and it sometimes has value and sometimes not .. I think solved the null problem , but now .. if the column doesn't have value it will put any of other rows value randomly and I really don't know how to fix that . @kRiZ

Comment: Yes, that could be a cell reuse issue. Have a check to see if the value is null and then set values accordingly.

Comment: So if the value is null , which is okay in my app to not be filled .. how to solve this cell reuse issue

Comment: hi @kRiZ I really need your help here with the cell reuse issue, it's happening a lot with me, but no one believes that parse has such issue. would you tell me how to fix it and if you have any article about the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for the re-use issue:

```
ParseObject gallery =  object.getParseObject("ImgName");
if (gallery != null) {
    String name=gallery.getString("name");
    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
    nameTextView.setText(name);
} else {
    nameTextView.setText(""); // or any other default value you want to set
}
```

NOTE:
The cell re-use issue is not on Parse. Cell re-use is a general concept used by the ListView. The cells are recycled for performance by Android. We just have to protect it from re-using old values.

Comment: Thanks .. do you any prove that there is re-use issue in parse ? I searched but I couldn't find

Comment: No, it's not an issue with Parse. See update to my answer.